# What is the correct formula for $ n $-dimensional spherical harmonics?

Tags: spherical-harmonics

In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Higher_dimensions), the formula for $ n $-dimensional spherical harmonics is given as $$ Y_{\ell_1, ..., \ell_{n-1}}( \theta_1, \dots \theta_{n-1} ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{i \ell_1 \theta_1} \prod_{j = 2}^{n-1} {}_j \bar{P}^{\ell_{j-1}}_{\ell_j}( \theta_j ) , $$
where the indices satisfy $ | \ell_1 | \le \ell_2 \le ... \le \ell_{n−1} $ and the eigenvalue is $ − \ell_{n-1} ( \ell_{n-1} + n − 2) $, i.e., $$ \Delta_{S^{n-1}} Y_{\ell_1, ..., \ell_{n-1}}( \theta_1, \dots \theta_{n-1} ) = - \ell_{n-1} ( \ell_{n-1} + n − 2) Y_{\ell_1, ..., \ell_{n-1}}( \theta_1, \dots \theta_{n-1} ) ,$$ where $ \Delta_{S^{n-1}} $ is the [Laplace-Beltrami operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator) on the $ n $-sphere $ S^{n-1} $. The functions $ {}_j \bar{P}^{\ell_{j-1}}_{\ell_j}( \theta_j ) $ in the product are defined in terms of the Legendre function:
$$ {}_j \bar{P}^\ell_{L}( \theta ) = \sqrt{\frac{2L + j - 1}{2} \frac{(L + \ell + j - 2)!}{(L - \ell)!}} \sin^{\frac{2 - j}{2}}( \theta ) P^{-\left(\ell + \frac{j-2}{2}\right)}_{L+\frac{j-2}{2}}(\cos \theta) , $$
where $$ P^{-\mu}_{\gamma}( x ) = \frac{1}{\Gamma( 1 + \mu )} \left( \frac{1 - x}{1 + x} \right)^{\mu / 2} F\left( - \gamma , \gamma + 1; 1 + \mu; \frac{1 - x}{2} \right) , $$
and $ F\left( \alpha , \beta; \gamma; z \right) $ is the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).
However, in page 1554 in [Higuchi (1987)](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.527513), a paper also cited in the Wikipedia article, the formula is given as $$ Y_{\ell_1, ..., \ell_{n-1}}( \theta_1, \dots \theta_{n-1} ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{i \ell_1 \theta_1} \prod_{j = 2}^{n-1} {}_j \bar{P}^{\ell_{n-2}}_{\ell_j}( \theta_j ) , $$ where the difference is in the superscript of $ \bar{P} $ and all other quantities are same.

What is the correct formula for the $ n $-dimensional spherical harmonics?